# MySql store "mm:ss" as "hh:mm"

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP with MySQL.

I have a table in which there is a filed with data type `time`.

From PHP application's time picker I am receiving an input data from this field as `13:00` or `14:00` (`hh:mm` format).

If I store it direct to the table then it will be stored like `00:13:00` or `00:14:00` (`hh:mm:ss` format).

Thus, the `hh:mm` is automatically gets converted to `mm:ss`.

The question is how can I store this input `13:00` as `13:00:00` in database table.

I can append `:00` at the end of the input data I am receiving but I don't think it is a proper way.

Can anybody guide me how to do it?

Comment: That's a plenty proper way, as you know that the format you will always be receiving is in `hh:mm` format. As long as that format is consistent, you can reliably convert to `hh:mm:ss` format by just appending `:00` to the end before storage. You've answered your own question - asking for an approach other than what you've already talked about just makes your question too broad since you're not providing enough detail (e.g. your code) as to how the input data is produced, sent, and handled.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.5.24

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742475/mysql-how-to-set-time-data-type-to-be-only-hhmm-in-database

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.5 you can set the field stamp type for the table

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in several formats, described in Section 9.1.3, [“Date and Time Literals”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

So you should be able to use `HH:MM` as your format for the field and then pass values as you are now